# How can I customize vscode's diff editor display to ignore certain differences?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my vscode extension I want to compare expected vs actual test results in the diff editor.  Expected results yaml files contain expressions which are dynamically substituted, and in the side-by-side editor I want to control which differences are highlighted.

Expected:

```
   request:
     url: '${baseUrl}/movies/${id}'
     method: GET
   #...
```

Actual:

```
  request:
    url: 'http://localhost/api/movies/435b30ad' # (diff should be ignored)
    method: GET
  #...
```

Is there a straightforward way I can supply the diffs myself?

At the moment, after opening the diff editor, I'm applying decorations like so:

```js
    async diffResults(expected: vscode.Uri, actual: vscode.Uri) {
        await vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.diff', expected, actual);
        const expectedEditor = await this.findEditor(expected);
        if (expectedEditor) {
            this.decorator.applyDecorations(expectedEditor);
        }
        const actualEditor = await this.findEditor(actual);
        if (actualEditor) {
            this.decorator.applyDecorations(actualEditor);
        }
    }
```

However, my decorations are overlaid on top of the default diff decorations rather than superseding them.  Furthermore, I feel that the decorator approach is not the right way to handle this.  If possible I'd like to supply the actual diffs myself to the editor, and let vscode handle the decorations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe not, the only customisation possible are the `diffEditor` settings listed [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings).